# Multiple instances of bind on debian

Tags: debian, bind, domain-name-system

I want to run two instances of bind on a server, one for authoritative answers and one for recursive queries.
[MaraDNS](http://maradns.org/) can easily be configured to run multiple instances. You just add a line for each instance in /etc/default/maradns file, stating configuration file for that instance

What is the best way of doing this with bind in debian ? Copying the initscript and modifying paths seams like a hack.

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @Chris S, there have been exploits in the past that cause cause problems, when Bind is acting as both an Authoriative and Recursive roles.  Most security pros suggest that you should never have a single DNS server perform both roles.  Given the security concern, you would probably want to run multiple instances because you can't afford extra boxes, and/or don't want to mess with VMs.

Comment: Like @Zoredache said, we want to seperate recursive & authoritative servers. And we want to do this with minimum hassle, so I want to do it with two bind instances listening on two IPs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume that you have these listening on different interfaces... you can make a second bind configuration directory (or at least a separate `named2.conf` or something) and a copy of `/etc/init.d/bind9`, and use the `-c` flag to `/usr/sbin/named` in the "other" bind9 initscript to have the second copy of bind load the second configuration.  You'll need to update the other stuff in the initscript like PIDFILE, and of make sure each one uses a different working directory in the bind configuration.